# Costum SQL Erros inside Try Catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, try-catch

How can I constumize SQL erros in a Try Catch block.

```
try {
        const event = await Event.findByPk(event_id);
        if (!event) {
            throw Error("Event not found");
        }
        await Event.update({ name:name, date:date }, {
            where: {
            id: event.id
            }
        });
}
catch(error) {
        return res.status(400).json({status: "error", message: error.message});
}
    
return res.json({
        status: "success"
});
```

If the Event.update query fails, can show something like:

```
{
 "status": "error",
 "message": "column \"name\" does not exist"
}
```

And I want to show something like this:

```
{
 "status": "error",
 "message": "Internal Server error"
}
```

Comment: In the catch block, set the message to the value you want: `return res.status(400).json({status: "error", message: "Internal Server Error"});`

Answer (score -1):

This is what you should have in the catch block. There is no need for the 'return' in the catch block:

```js
    try {
            const event = await Event.findByPk(event_id);
            if (!event) {
                throw Error("Event not found");
            }
            await Event.update({ name:name, date:date }, {
                where: {
                id: event.id
                }
            });
    }
    catch(error) {
            res.status(400).send({status: "error", message: error});
    }
```

Comment: If you don't return the error response you've just built, then it'll be discarded, and the following line that returns a success response will be executed.